# Spotfire limit data using expression by date

Tags: date, expression, limit, spotfire

I don't want to use a filter, I need to use the "Limit data using expression:" to only show dates "1-1-2015 to 12-31-2016". My date column is ([Date]). Something like this is what I've tried but it doesn't work:
1/1/2015<=([Date])<1/1/2017

What am I doing wrong?

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you data type is actually a date and you are comparing dates with dates, so try:

```
date("1/1/2015") <= [date] and [date] < date("1/1/2017")
```